# Specify the language of the app in the marketplace?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I just tried to submit my new Windows Phone 7 app to the Market Place and realized that apparently I have set English as my project language instead of German. In the [app hub application submission walkthrough - step 2](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/app_submission_walkthrough_description) it says

> Provide the following information to submit your application. You'll repeat these steps for each language that your XAP package supports.

And in the next page as the only "supported language" English is shown.

How can I put German instead?

Thanks

PS: Does it even matter? What if I just provide a German description even though it says English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your changing the native language of the app. Open properties of your project, get the assembly info and you should see a list of languages (I'm not exactly sure as dont have VS on this machine).

The other option is to add / change the NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute in the assemblyinfo file. The new version would look like:

```
[NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("de")]
```